# .htaccess issues with wordpress after moving website

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess

I have transferred  my website subdomain to main public_html  directory,
but root directory taking all file link form sub directory, here is my .htaccess

what is new htaccess code for polestarllp.com  main directory

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /polestarnew/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /polestarnew/index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`.htaccess` code for `polestarllp.com` **main directory**

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

You also need to change in database **wp_options** table `siteurl` and `home` to new site url

Comment: I have one issue more i do not know , my front-page.php  file not working on server , my browser taking old fornt-page.php file

Comment: i have changes every thing was ok , after 24 hours , fornt-page.php is getting old url form directory old directory

Comment: @SanjayYadav Change your front  page  go to  admin > Settings > Reading panel. select your `Front page:`